# Redirect user with invalid SSL certificate with nicer page and message

Tags: ssl

When I use cloudflare and if my domain has invalid certificate (due to rate limit from letsencrypt) it will show me a nice colorful page with peace message about having invalid ssl. If I dont use cloudflare, the Chrome browser will tell people that the site with invalid certificate might stealing credit card (the word is pretty harsh).

So, is it possible to redirect user with a nicer page to show that he has invalid certificate when browsing my site?

Example if he goes to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), if the SSL is invalid then redirect him to nicer page like:

https://anothersite.com/yougotinvalidssl.php

How can cloudflare did that?

EDIT (I took from my comment below):

I have the reason why it has rate limit at this point, I did multiple test to request the limit for SSL backup script and accidentally deleted the previous SSL success request (that was my mistake). So, it's not an issue of making the certificate valid or the renewal process has no problem at this point. It could be that one day a similar issue like `ISRG Root X1` appear again and will make the certificate become invalid (and this has nothing to do with our side to hunt for solution but the SSL provider). So, I'm just a looking a long term solution to check this like what cloudflare able to do

Comment: I have read somewhere it seems this is not easy to achieve. But could someone explain how cloudflare did that ?

Comment: I think you may be looking at solving the wrong issue here. Instead of looking for a way to display a nice page when you have an SSL error, instead you should look at ensuring your SSL certificate is valid.

You mentioned Let's Encrypt rate limiting you. A certificate should only need to be renewed once every ~90 days. So, if setup to run at a correct interval, should never run into a rate limit.

Comment: I put my previous comment in question: Also the reason I ask this is because mostly I'm dealing with new automated server installation script. eg: Deleting domain, creating new domain from scratch. So, the server will not retain information of the interval time for the cert renewal process like you mentioned. The limit will end tomorrow and I'm not gonna have this issue again because I have successfully wrote an SSL backup script for this. But, like I said invalid certificate will come anytime like ISRG ROOT X1 issue.

Comment: **Cloudflare** can show a nice error because they **have their own certificate (for your domain) which IS valid** (on their many servers) even if the cert you got yourself (on your origin server) is not. To do this yourself you need to get a valid certificate. You could then use the valid certificate to tell people not to use the invalid certificate, but why waste their time when you can just use the valid certificate?

Comment: Thankyou. Don't know why you still ask me the reason when I already gave reason in the comment and question and usecase like ISRG ROOT X1 issue .